# pdf attachment not working rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, base64

In rails 3  when we attach pdf document in email through action mailer,
that pdf is not come as a attachment in e-mail, its come in body like

```
Date: Wed, 29 Dec 2010 19:56:12 +0530
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/pdf;
 charset=UTF-8;
 filename=free_book.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=free_book.pdf
Content-ID: <4d1b450431abc_### @BHUSHANF.mail>

JVBERi0xLjMKJf////8KMSAwIG9iago8PCAvQ3JlYXRvciAoUHJhd24pCi9Q
cm9kdWNlciAoUHJhd24pCj4+CmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8IC9UeXBlIC9Q
YWdlcwovQ291bnQgMQovS2lkcyBbNSAwIFJdCj4+CmVuZG9iagozIDAgb2Jq
Cjw8IC9UeXBlIC9DYXRhbG9nCi9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKNCAw
IG9iago8PCAvTGVuZ3RoIDU4OAo+PgpzdHJlYW0KL0RldmljZVJHQiBjcwow
LjAwMCAwLjAwMCAwLjAwMCBzY24KL0RldmljZVJHQiBDUwowLjAwMCAwLjAw
MCAwLjAwMCBTQ04KcQoKQlQKNDEgNzQzLjUwNCBUZAovRjEuMCA4IFRmCls8
NGY3MjY0NjU3Mj5dIFRKCkVUCgoKQlQKNDEgNzM0LjI1NiBUZAovRjEuMCA4
IFRmCls8NTM3NTZkNmQ2MTcyPiAtMzAgPDc5Pl0gVEoKRVQKCjAuMDAwIDAu
MDAwIDAuMDAwIHNjbgoKQlQKMTA4IDc0My41MDQgVGQKL0YxLjAgOCBUZgpb
PDQyNjE3NDYzNjgyMDQ0NjE3NDY1MmY1NDY5NmQ2NTNhNTc+IDMwIDw2NTY0
MjA0NDY1NjMyMDMyMzkyMDMxMzkzYTM1MzYzYTMxMzEyMDJiMzAzNTMzMzAy
MDMyMzAzMTMwPl0gVEoKRVQKCjAuMDAwIDAuMDAwIDAuMDAwIHNjbgoKQlQK
MzAyIDc0My41MDQgVGQKL0YxLjAgOCBUZgpbPDRmNzI2NDY1NzIyMDYyNjE3
NDYzNjgyMDZlNmYzYTMxMzgzMjMxMzEzNTM5Mzk+XSBUSgpFVAoKMC4wMDAg
MC4wMDAgMC4wMDAgc2NuCgpCVAoyNDIuMTQ4IDY5OC44ODggVGQKL0YxLjAg
MTIgVGYKWzw1MDcyNmY2NDc1NjM3NDIwNmM2OTczNzQyMDY5NzMyMDZlNmY3
NDIwNjY+IDMwIDw2Zjc1NmU2NDJlPl0gVEoKRVQKClEKCmVuZHN0cmVhbQpl
bmRvYmoKNSAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZQovUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCi9S
ZXNvdXJjZXMgPDwgL1Byb2NTZXQgWy9QREYgL1RleHQgL0ltYWdlQiAvSW1h
Z2VDIC9JbWFnZUldCi9Gb250IDw8IC9GMS4wIDYgMCBSCj4+Cj4+Ci9NZWRp
YUJveCBbMCAwIDYxMi4wIDc5Mi4wXQovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFIKPj4KZW5k
b2JqCjYgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0VuY29kaW5nIC9XaW5BbnNpRW5jb2RpbmcKL1R5
cGUgL0ZvbnQKL0Jhc2VGb250IC9IZWx2ZXRpY2EKL1N1YnR5cGUgL1R5cGUx
Cj4+CmVuZG9iagp4cmVmCjAgNwowMDAwMDAwMDAwIDY1NTM1IGYgCjAwMDAw
MDAwMTUgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDA3MSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMTI4
IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAxNzcgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDgxNiAwMDAw
MCBuIAowMDAwMDAwOTk0IDAwMDAwIG4gCnRyYWlsZXIKPDwgL1Jvb3QgMyAw
IFIKL0luZm8gMSAwIFIKL1NpemUgNwo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKMTA5MQolJUVP
Rgo=
```

Comment: hi,
My problem is solved.

in rails 3.0.3  body tag is important when attachment is done.

Working code

 attachments['test.pdf'] = genearteOrderPDF(orders, orderBatch)

  mail(:to => conf['to_email'],
         :from => conf['from_email'],
         :body =>"this tag is important when do any attachment",
         :subject => "Oders pdf ")

Comment: Can you show, how you are adding attachment?

Comment: Bhushan, your comment is actually a answer. Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not define a view for the action. I had the same problem as you and by creating a view in app/views/test_mailer/view.text.erb the need for a :body was rendered obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the `:body` tag is not present in the `mail` function.